# Angular5:Obesrvables error in render the list

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am trying to learn Observable in angular5

Component.ts file

```
export class CommerceComponent implements OnInit {

public List$: Observable<any>;

getData(id){

 this.List$ = this.gateway.search(id);

  }
}
```

Services

```
search(id){


        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('token',this.cookieService.get('token'));
        fd.append('search',id);
         return this.http.post(config.url+'search',fd).map((res: Response) => res.json())

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="deal-boxes" *ngIf="(List$ | async).length">
      <div class="deal1"  *ngFor="let  item of List$ | async">{{item}}
    </div>
    </div>
```

But i got the following error in my console

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Comment: try after changing condition of ngIf from `*ngIf="(List$ | async).length"` to `*ngIf="List$"` or remove if condition

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to check `length` property within your `ngIf` before you got any data from observable. you should store your resolved `async` value into a variable and then access properties.

check this in docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable